# Timeline item update error

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have a bundle of timelineitems using **Mirror API**, Now I am trying to change content of a timeline from bundle. But the below error occurs

```
An error occurred from update timeline : com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}
```

And update method is something like below

```
public static TimelineItem updateTimelineItem(Credential credential,
        String itemId, String newText) {
    try {
        Mirror.Timeline timeline = getMirror(credential).timeline();
        TimelineItem timelineItem = timeline.get(itemId).execute();

        timelineItem.setText(newText);

        return timeline.update(itemId, timelineItem).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("\nAn error occurred from update timeline : " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

First I try to retrieve the timeline item, when I write execute, then the error occurred

```
Mirror.Timeline timeline = getMirror(credential).timeline();
TimelineItem timelineItem = timeline.get(itemId).execute();
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't completely clear from the exception you've posted, but it looks like the itemId isn't valid. How are you getting this itemId and can you verify if it is the timeline.get or the timeline.update that is causing the problem?

Comment: I set timeline ID manually, when I created timeline item bundle. then just try to change text using update method. So I know the timeline item ID.

Comment: The timeline Item ID is always created automatically when you insert a new card and is different from the Bundle ID. You would have to read the response of your insert request to get the real Item ID, or use a timeline.list to find your card with the item id again.

Comment: I check the ID, it is ok. when I try to execute then it gives error. timeline.get(itemId).execute()

Comment: What do you mean by "ok"? Is it the same ID that is _returned_ when you do the original timeline.insert? Why are you setting the ID manually?